# How do you build the "release" configuration in Monodevelop?

Tags: .net, build, monodevelop, buildconfiguration

When creating a Monodevelop project, or when opening a typical Visual Studio project, there are 2 build configurations: "Debug" and "Release".

The default is "Debug", and building from the Build menu only runs the Debug build.

This should be a trivial task, but I see no option to build a different build configuration (in the menus or in the project or solution settings, short of outright deleting the "Debug" configuration). How can I build the "release" configuration?

(The "Configuration" dropdowns in the project and solution settings actually act as tabs; they don't change the default.) I [searched for "build configuration" in the Monodevelop documentation](http://monodevelop.com/Special%3aSearch?search=%22build+configuration%22&type=fulltext), but nothing relevant came up.

Answer (score 2):

What version of MonoDevelop are you running?

On my mac, I am running version 2.8.8.4 of MonoDevelop. The menu item:

"Project > Active Configuration" shows two options: Debug | x86, and Release | x86. If you check the "Release | x86" option, you will build the "Release" version. This choice is reflected in a "spinbox" in the centre of the "toolbar". When I choose either "Debug", or "Release" it changes. You can change it in this "spinbox" also.

I just checked to make sure, but after I built my project, I get the new "Release" file.

Maybe you have to update, or reinstall your MonoDevelop? This feature has always worked for me.

I hope this helps you. CHEERS!