# How to change Active configuration in monodevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

I'm following [these steps to build sdrsharp](http://rtlsdr.org/softwarelinux) on stable Debian. So fr, everything went without a hitch, but I can't figure out this step:

- cd into the new sdrsharp directory and then load monodevelop and open the sdrsharp.sln project. If the .sln doesn't open use a text editor to open the .sln file and at the end of the first line change the 12.00 to 11.00. Older versions of monodevelop don't understand the VS2012 header.
- Set the Active Configuration from Debug|x86 to Release|x86.

The first one is just given for context, monodevelop has no problem opening the file. But how do I change the Actove Configuration?

Monodevelops internal help is broken, I have no experience with monodevelop or similiar tools as I'm no coder, hence asking here.

**Edit to add**
The same question was [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438885/how-do-you-build-the-release-configuration-in-monodevelop), there should be an option under the "project" tab. But in my case, working from the downloaded .sln, all options under project are grayed out. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! The Version had to be changed back to 11 (first bullet point above, relevant to my special case), then reopen file, then it's opened as a project, not as a text file and all the options work.
Take home lessen: That a progeam opens a file without complaining does noit mean there's no error.